# Advanced animations question (websites). How to make image animations like on the following website

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, animation, css-animations

http://www.mikimottes.com/ this is the website I'm asking about!
I've learned how to make simple animations. But when I discovered this website, I fell in love with it and want to learn how to make such websites. And I'm wondering how can for example the images animations, how are they developed? I have a few suggestions that it may be something related to GIFs but how then the GIF can be controlled? As sometimes animations of images stop and then something triggers them to animate. It seems impossible with GIFs. It doesn't seem like a js animation. Please assist me on that question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These effects are based on plain [CSS animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations). You can easily see the styles and parameters used by a given animation with your browser developer tools (e.g. in Firefox, right click on an animation and select "Inspect Element").

For instance the little blue critter hovering between the two wind turbines in the top left corner is animated using this image: [image: example animation]

To get a very basic idea of how it's done, you can look for instance at [this blog post](https://medium.com/@robertcooper_rc/animating-a-sprite-sheet-with-css-ca15e2664)

I suspect you would need some extra tool like a decent paint program to automate some steps (e.g. using layers and generating the succession of frames automatically from a collection of drawings) but I guess it can be done by hand for simple cases.

Comment: Thank you very very much!